# Why does Mono Develop(Unity) remove my custom define directives from the script by itself?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

Okay so my c# code snippet goes like this:

```
#if ASSET_BUNDLE_PKG
    loadfromAssetBundle();
#else
    loadfromResources();
#endif
```

I have another script that does this: "If it detects the "Asset Bundle Package" in the project, it adds the define directive ASSET_BUNDLE_PKG to unity. If it detects that the package is not present, it removes the define directive ASSET_BUNDLE_PKG from unity." Simple.

Now when I add the package and run the code, everything works fine and unity loads from asset bundle.

When I remove the package and run the code, everything works find and unity loads from the resources.

When I **AGAIN** add the package, here's what happens:

1- Mono develop reverts the code back to:

```
loadfromAssetBundle();
```

that is, it removes the #if statements completely.

2- Obviously I encounter compiler errors since I cannot load from the asset bundle if the package is not present! That is what the #if statements were there for in the first place!

Who is altering the script all by itself?

Comment: Well it found  the ASSET_BUNDLE_PKG compile flag was set, so it compiled it that way.. Thats how its supposed to work

Comment: Lets put this simple. My initial code was 5 lines as you can see. After I reload the package, mono develop magically shows the the code to be 1 line. Why does it remove the 4 lines (#if statements) from the script. I mean they are completely removed.

Comment: Why do you think MonoDevelop is doing this? Do you see something different if you open in Visual Studio?

Comment: Installing Visual Studio just to check that!

Comment: You should also notice that Unity gave up MonoDevelop in favor of other editors, like Visual Studio https://blogs.unity3d.com/2018/01/05/discontinuing-support-for-monodevelop-unity-starting-in-unity-2018-1/

Answer (score 0):

Okay so here was the problem.

The package contained a script that derived from "xyz.cs". And the script which contained the code that I have posted in the question also derived from the script "xyz.cs". Both were using the same file which may have caused mono develop's weird behavior. I made a copy of "xyz.cs", renamed it and placed it in the package and updated the name wherever it was used in the package.